# Debezium throws an error when connecting to RDS Aurora instance

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, amazon-aurora, debezium

Here are elements of my infrastructure related to this problem:

- RDS Aurora, which runs on MySql 5.7 with binlogs enabled in row-based mode
- AWS MSK which runs Kafka cluster (I don't know if that's important, but it runs on version 2.7.0)
- EC2 instance with Kafka-connect (as a Docker image) where runs a source connector which uses Debezium

I'm trying to use Debezium to get all changes from the Aurora instance and put them to Kafka but unfortunately, it is not working. Here is the connector configuration I'm using:

```json
{
        "name": "aurora-connector-test",
        "config": {
                "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
                "tasks.max": "1",
                "database.hostname": "URL",
                "database.port": "3306",
                "database.user": "debezium",
                "database.password": "PASSWORD",
                "database.server.id": "129056",
                "database.server.name": "aurora-connector-db-test",
                "database.allowPublicKeyRetrieval":"true",
                "database.include.list": "DATABASE",
                "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "BROKER1:9092,BROKER2:9092,BROKER3:9092",
                "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.DATABASE",
                "transforms": "route",
                "transforms.route.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
                "transforms.route.regex": "([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)",
                "transforms.route.replacement": "$3"
        }
}
```

After creating a connector using the above configuration I can see that Debezium is able to connect to the Aurora database because it's listing all available tables in the logs. Sadly, at some point, I'm getting  `Communications link failure` error. Here is a chunk of logs:

```
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.106265621Z 2021-01-12 08:47:39,106 INFO   MySQL|aurora-connector-db-test|snapshot  Step 5: committing transaction   [io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader]
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.107645625Z 2021-01-12 08:47:39,107 ERROR  MySQL|aurora-connector-db-test|snapshot  Failed due to error: Aborting snapshot due to error when last running 'SHOW FULL TABLES IN `sys` where Table_Type = "BASE TABLE"': Communications link failure
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113018742Z org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Communications link failure
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113022120Z
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113025636Z The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. Error code: 0; SQLSTATE: 08S01.
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113029640Z     at io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.wrap(AbstractReader.java:230)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113033236Z     at io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.failed(AbstractReader.java:207)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113036512Z     at io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader.execute(SnapshotReader.java:847)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113039728Z     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113055546Z     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113059492Z     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113062958Z Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113066762Z
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113070570Z The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113074098Z     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113077538Z     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113080901Z     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113084338Z     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113087583Z     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113090489Z     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113093761Z     at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.lambda$patternBasedFactory$1(JdbcConnection.java:191)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113096988Z     at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.connection(JdbcConnection.java:789)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113100397Z     at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.connection(JdbcConnection.java:784)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113103714Z     at io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader.execute(SnapshotReader.java:748)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113107314Z     ... 3 more
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113110461Z Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113113684Z
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113117610Z The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113121639Z     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113125289Z     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113128514Z     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113131552Z     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113134638Z     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113137876Z     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113140913Z     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113148186Z     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113151641Z     at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113155079Z     at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:152)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113158553Z     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:955)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113162110Z     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113165344Z     ... 10 more
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113168317Z Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113171590Z     at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113174792Z     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113178326Z     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113181678Z     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113185328Z     at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113188827Z     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113192354Z     at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113195838Z     at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65)
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113199398Z     ... 13 more
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113249277Z 2021-01-12 08:47:39,113 ERROR  ||  WorkerSourceTask{id=aurora-connector-test-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask]
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113256190Z 2021-01-12 08:47:39,113 INFO   MySQL|aurora-connector-db-test|task  Stopping MySQL connector task   [io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask]
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113259635Z 2021-01-12 08:47:39,113 INFO   MySQL|aurora-connector-db-test|task  ChainedReader: Stopping the snapshot reader   [io.debezium.connector.mysql.ChainedReader]
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113263070Z 2021-01-12 08:47:39,113 INFO   MySQL|aurora-connector-db-test|task  Discarding 0 unsent record(s) due to the connector shutting down   [io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader]
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113266516Z 2021-01-12 08:47:39,113 INFO   MySQL|aurora-connector-db-test|task  Discarding 0 unsent record(s) due to the connector shutting down   [io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader]
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.113420628Z 2021-01-12 08:47:39,113 INFO   MySQL|aurora-connector-db-test|task  [Producer clientId=aurora-connector-test-dbhistory] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.   [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer]
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.114679266Z 2021-01-12 08:47:39,114 INFO   MySQL|aurora-connector-db-test|task  Connector task finished all work and is now shutdown   [io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask]
connect_1  | 2021-01-12T08:47:39.114799622Z 2021-01-12 08:47:39,114 INFO   ||  [Producer clientId=connector-producer-aurora-connector-test-0] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 30000 ms.   [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer]
```

I know that my security groups on AWS are configured correctly because I'm able to connect to the Aurora instance remotely from the EC2 instance. Additionally, I was using a very similar connector configuration for MySQL instead of Aurora on the same EC2 instance and it was able to create messages in the same Kafka - hence I think that the problem is with Aurora configuration (I'm using the default configuration with row-based binlogs enabled), but maybe I'm wrong.

Do you guys have any ideas on that issue?

Answer (score 1):

The debezium user needs these privileges: SELECT, RELOAD, SHOW DATABASES, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, LOCK TABLES. My only guess is to check if the user has all of them.